# Is there a way to fix a BLE advertising interval in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm making an Android application and I'd need to send advertising data at a fixed advertising interval.

I've tried setting an advertising interval value using the `setInterval()` function from `AdvertisingSetParameters` class, but when I check the advertising interval in a scanner device using *nRF Connect* or *BLE Scanner* applications, it shows a lot of variance between advertising intervals.

To sum up, **I'd like to know if it's possible to fix an advertising interval in an Android application**.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Have you tried using a Bluetooth sniffer or something that is more accurate than an Android BLE scanner?

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder#setInterval(int)), you can set the advertising interval using the `setInterval()` function of the `AdvertisingSetParameters` class, as you said. The advertising interval set is fixed.

The phenomena you are experiencing could be due of two possible causes:

- Your smartphone is broadcasting another set of advertising packet with different advertising interval
- the scan of BLE advertising messages it fails to capture all packets as often as they were emitted, maybe you are making test in an enviroment crowned of BLE devices